# No module named 'winrandom' when using pycrypto

Tags: python, windows, paramiko, pycrypto

I already spent 2 days trying to install pyCrypto for Paramiko module.

So, first issue I had faced was this:

```
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 31
, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 4
7, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 26,
in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

It is very fun actually because I use Windows and it doesn't care about uppercase. I changed a folder name from crypto to Crypto and this particular issue disappeared.

Now it wants winrandom:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 31
, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 4
7, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 26,
in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py", line
 89, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", li
ne 28, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import OSRNG
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.p
y", line 34, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.OSRNG.nt import new
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", li
ne 28, in <module>
    import winrandom
ImportError: No module named 'winrandom'
```

When I try to install it through PIP I fail with:

```
Cannot export PyInit_winrandom: symbol not defined

build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\winrandom.o:winrandom.c:(.text+0x12): undefined
 reference to `Py_InitModule'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Seems like it doesn't support Python3.4.

Is there any way to make it all works in Win7 x86 with Python3.4 installed?

Installed modules:

```
crypto (1.1.0)
ecdsa (0.11)
Fabric (1.9.0)
paramiko (1.14.0)
pip (1.5.6)
pyasn1 (0.1.7)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
PyYAML (3.11)
rsa (3.1.4)
setuptools (2.1)
```

Python version 3.4.1

Comment: On which operating system ? and version ?

Comment: Win7 x86 + Python 3.4.1

Comment: Have you installed Paramiko correctly ? (like shown on this link: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/README)

Comment: I have installed Paramiko by PIP, I suppose it is OK.

Comment: Note that the PyCrypto project has been [discontinued](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/238), apparently the [PyCryptodome project](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) aims to be a drop-in replacement. Personally, I've found the [`pycryptography` project](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) to be a far better API.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Problem is solved by editing string in crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py:

```
import winrandom
```

to

```
from . import winrandom
```

Comment: I have the same problem after editing this line, using Python 3.5 32bit and Windows 8.1 :s

Comment: Thank you very much! I have the same problem with Python 3.5.1 32bit on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Excellent. However, how does this work? It imports winrandom but not winrandom's attributes and things.

Answer (score 16):

Super easy fix for `ImportError: No module named 'winrandom'` - this is where python is located on my Windows 10 system:

`C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`

But you have to go further to find the right file to update, so go here:

`C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py`

Open the `nt.py` in any text editor and change just the line near the top:

```
import winrandom
```

should be:

```
from . import winrandom
```

Save the file - re-run what you were originally trying to run and you should be good.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I though this Python was supposed to be such an easy to use language, but as an experienced C# and PhP developer, I keep finding myself googling these kind of fixes for problems that should not be there