# Microsoft Windows Python-3.6 PyCrypto installation error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, pycrypto, python-3.6

`pip install pycrypto` works fine with python3.5.2 but fails with python3.6 with the following error:

> inttypes.h(26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The file include\pyport.h in Python installation directory does not have **#include < stdint.h >** anymore.  This leaves **intmax_t** undefined.

A workaround for Microsoft VC compiler is to force include **stdint.h** via OS environment variable **CL**:

1. Open command prompt
2. Setup VC environment by runing vcvars*.bat (choose file name depending on VC version and architecture)
3. set CL=-FI"Full-Path\stdint.h" (use real value for Full-Path for the environment)
4. pip install pycrypto

Comment: Has this been patched into Windows Python?

Comment: Why hasn't this been patched into Windows Python distribution? For the record, I was able to use vcvarsall.bat `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`.

Comment: Has this been reported on the Python bug tracker? If so, can someone provide the reference? If not, maybe someone could do so.

Comment: The issue was reported at https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/221. The problem is with pycrypto itself, which supplies an incomplete ```stdint.h```, and I've added an explanation of the fix required to that bug report.

Comment: Admin privileges are needed in case Python environment is in a protected/shared location

Comment: I did not need admin privileges on Windows 7 with UAC.

Comment: Try windows 10 and pip, not setup.py

Comment: For me, steps 1+2 could be shortened to: **From Start menu, run "Visual C++ 2015 x86 Native Build Tools Command Prompt"**

Comment: also if you build it with **VS 2017**, the header location should be modified as follows: **set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\stdint.h** - of course _14.16.27023_ number depends on VS version, mine is 15.9.

Comment: As of today, the best advice is to switch to pycryptodome. See bhuvan karuturi's answer

Comment: This worked for me in Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 (aka Visual Studio 14) using `set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%\include\stdint.h"`

Comment: What baffles me is that this is STILL not fixed in September 2022. Facepalm. Thanks for the workaround

Answer (score 37):

I've succeeded install pycrypto 2.6.1 on python 3.6, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017.

1. Open "x86_x64 Cross-Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" with administrator privilege in start menu.
2. `set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdint.h"`
3. `pip install pycrypto`

[image]

Comment: Finally working solution!! Just make sure to check the actual version of MSVC folder, I had `14.12.25827`. Thanks mate

Comment: Thanks @Marko :-) For me these 3 command worked. 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvarsx86_amd64.bat 2. set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\stdint.h" 3. pip install pycrypto==2.6.1

Comment: I'm thinking in Donate PayPal Button to this guy

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to [user1960422](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960422/user1960422)'s answer. 
PowerShell steps for pycrypto 2.6.1 (via simple-crypt) / Python 3.6 / Windows 10:

```
$env:VCINSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC"
$env:CL="-FI`"$env:VCINSTALLDIR\INCLUDE\stdint.h`""
```

[Successful simple-crypt / pycrypto install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Mwn.png)

I also needed to follow the answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24822876/8751739 to fix a `winrandom` module error.

Comment: That helped in PowerShell, but also I needed [Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe) for the linking to succeed.

Comment: visual studio 2017 build tools and in my case the VCINSTALLDIR is at VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023

Answer (score 16):

Use **PyCryptodome** instead of **pycrypto**. pycrypto is [discontinued](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/173) and is no longer actively supported. PyCryptodome exposes almost the same API as pycrypto ([source](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/vs_pycrypto.html)).

Comment: This question is about compilation problem and what to use instead

Answer (score 6):

I've succeeded install pycrypo 2.6.1 on python 3.6 and windows 10.

1. Set an environment variable like below.
    [image: visual studio installed directory]
2. Open cmd.exe
3. Activate virtualenv
4. Download pycrypto 2.6.1 release from github and unzip it.
5. set an environment variable for pycrypto

   `set CL=/FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%\\INCLUDE\\stdint.h" %CL%`
6. Run setup command 

   `python setup.py install`
7. my result is here
   [image]

I would be glad if this could be help someone.

Comment: How is it different from the original answer?

Comment: @user1602 you don't have to do the following steps in original answer
---
1. Open command prompt with admin privileges
2. Run vsvars32.bat from your version of VC

Comment: In your case you set VCINSTALLDIR manually, where I do it via vsvars32.bat. In the end you are suggesting the same solution.

Answer (score 4):

For ppl who is encountering same situation as mine:

**Env**

- Windows 10 Enterprise v10.0.18363 Build 18363
- Python 3.8

**Steps**

1. Download **Microsoft C++ Build Tools** at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
2. Run above setup exe and install default components

   - MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
   - Windows 10 SDK
   - C++ CMake tools for windows
   - Testing tools core features - Build Tools
   - C++ AddressSanitizer(Experimental)
3. Reboot PC
4. Start menu > **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019**, a cmd window will pop up
5. Execute `set CL=-FI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\stdint.h"`
6. Run `pip install pycrypto` in a cmd window(may need admin privilege)

Comment: Saving a precious 1min for 2022 x64 folks: `set CL=-FI"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\stdint.h"`

Answer (score 2):

- Uninstall your current Python version
- Install Python for amd64 architecture
- Follow the other accepted solutions:

  - open "x86_x64 Cross-Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017"
  - Add the new enviroment varible for your Visual Studio MSVC install path
  - `set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdint.h"`
  - `pip install pycrypto`

Answer (score 0):

For me this fixes it:

with Python 2, I have

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev  \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
     ...
```

with Python 3, I need

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     ...
```

Installing `python-dev python3-dev` fixes it for me!

Comment: This is Windows platform issue, not Ubuntu. Your answer is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvars64.bat
```

> ---
>
> ** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.14
> ** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
> ********************************************************************** [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools>set
> CL=-FI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdint.h"
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools>pip
> install pycrypto Collecting pycrypto   Using cached
> pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ...
> done Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto   Building wheel
> for pycrypto (setup.py) ... done   Created wheel for pycrypto:
> filename=pycrypto-2.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=528832
> sha256=250926fc0e06b4c1ed9c2fb16ad9b4723984ef68c1e5383b26c974235536a0ae
> Stored in directory:
> c:\users\volka\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local\pip\cache\wheels\9d\29\32\8b8f22481bec8b0fbe7087927336ec167faff2ed9db849448f
> Successfully built pycrypto Installing collected packages: pycrypto
> Successfully installed pycrypto-2.6.1
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).