# python/pip on Windows - 'cl.exe' failed (error code 1 exit status 2)

Tags: python, c++, windows, pip, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use pip (or easy_install) to install the coinbase library. I'm running Python 3.6. I keep getting errors which I suspect are related to C++ rather than the library I'm trying to install. The installer crashes with error code 1 and exit status 2. This is the error I receive, even when I try to install in the directory which includes cl.exe:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin>pip install coinbase
Requirement already satisfied: coinbase in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\coinbase-2.0.6-py3.6.egg
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.5 in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from coinbase)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from coinbase)
Collecting pycrypto>=2.6.1 (from coinbase)
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.5->coinbase)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.5->coinbase)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.5->coinbase)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.5->coinbase)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycrypto ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\leemo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-o4hcmg5p\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\leemo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwo7tf4vkpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto
  ...
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
  building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src/winrand.obj
  winrand.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(40): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ','
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(48): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(56): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(63): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(69): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(76): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(82): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(89): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(95): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\leemo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-o4hcmg5p\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\leemo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-paf4z6dk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(40): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(48): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(56): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(63): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(69): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(76): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(82): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(89): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(95): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\leemo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\leemo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-o4hcmg5p\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\leemo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-paf4z6dk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\leemo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-o4hcmg5p\pycrypto\
```

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error