# Problem installing pycrypto on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, whatsapp, pycrypto

I want to use https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/ repo. During the setup, it requires pycrypto package, but I am facing error. I have tried many ways from stackoverflow and github issues.

System OS - Windwows 10
Python - 3.7.1

### Error

```
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\jmd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JMD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-il7eha03\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JMD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ovghq181\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\jmd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\jmd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(40): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(48): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(56): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(63): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(69): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(76): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(82): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(89): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(95): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\jmd\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JMD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-il7eha03\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JMD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ovghq181\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JMD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-il7eha03\pycrypto\
```

Comment: Have you got all the requirements installed from the list in the docs? [Trying it out](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/#trying-it-out), and the python packages listed in [requirements.txt](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/master/requirements.txt) ?

Comment: Yes.. other all packages are installed successfully.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried installing on my similar system and I can confirm your problem I got the same error. I tried a suggestion, and I can confirm it fixes the error and I got PyCrypto to install sucessfully. See here: [Python - PyCrypto installation error (vc\cl.exe fails no matter what)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032787/python-pycrypto-installation-error-vc-cl-exe-fails-no-matter-what#comment77078562_45032787).

Comment: The full fix they link to is here: [2017-01-03 Building pycrypto on Windows](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/pymyinstall/helpsphinx/blog/2017/2017-01-03_pycrypto.html). Just be sure to do as they suggest "I finally decided to edit this file and to add just before the line of the error (which I’ll remove after):" Hopefully this works for you as it did for me.

Comment: Solution [link](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/pymyinstall/helpsphinx/blog/2017/2017-01-03_pycrypto.html) solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[2017-01-03 Building pycrypto on Windows](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/pymyinstall/helpsphinx/blog/2017/2017-01-03_pycrypto.html) Solved my problem. Earlier I tried the same solution, but I think  I was doing something wrong that time