# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been able to install `pycrypto` as follows, followed the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error/41843310#41843310).

[image]

But when I debug the project, then getting the following issue which seems to be related `Crypto`.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrandom'

[image]

`aut\token.py` line 3 is

```
from jose.jwt import get_unverified_claims
```

**UPDATE:1**

Then, I have run `pip install winrandom` and get the following error.

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and
>   'str'

[image]

**UPDATE:2**

When I rung the proposed command `pip install --proxy http://XXXX:80 git+https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git` with proxy(required) in the working environment, then I get a connection refused error as follows.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pip install winrandom`?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winrandom/1.2

Comment: @kichik, please see update.

Comment: Looks like it may have been resolved, but PyPI is out of date: https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/110

Comment: @CoryMadden How should I handle to get correct package, sorry I am newbie on python. Thanks a lot already for digging into the issue and bring it up.

Comment: @hotspring: I have set bounty on this.

Comment: @hotspring `self.id_version` seems not to be defined, so it is returning `None`. The when you try to compare `None >= "2.10.90"`, it gives you a `TypeError` as `None`'s type (`NoneType`) doesn't have a greater or equal than method for `str`s. The problem probably is that `self.id_version` should be defined before.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus : I got stuck on this and spent some reps on bounty.  What other course of action do I have?  I asked a question and was told this question was an exact duplicate.  Right now, I contemplating not using Python.  Do you want to promote Python or not?  Yours is an unhelpful comment.

Comment: @SMeaden You should keep in mind that Zero's comment is explaining why the question is poorly formatted and that this is in fact a helpful comment. The idea is to move the screen shot track back error into the the question as readable text rather than a screen shot, as screen shots do not allow for copy paste during the troubleshooting of your problem. No one here wants to type out the track back error when searching up possible issues/answer. The how to ask link is very helpful as it provides a question format that will result in the best kind of replies/answers.

Comment: I cannot see the code, only unloaded images.

Comment: Why are you using a proxy to connect to github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a common issue with pycrypto. This is a bug, but the project doesn't seem to be updated in the last couple years.

Digging over the issue, (https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt/issues/17)
It seems the poblem is solved by doing an edit to the import statement in `crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py`:

```
import winrandom

to

from . import winrandom
```

Comment: In my version of `nt.py` Line actually reads `from Crypto.Random.OSRNG import winrandom` .  Please advise.

Comment: Do you have `winrandom.py` in `crypto\Random\OSRNG` ? Try change to according to my answer and see if it helps

Comment: Same again, `c:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-package\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py` (no other copies of winrandom.py found) also reads `from Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom import *`

Answer (score 1):

As Vinny mentioned, this issue is known and solved in Pycrypto, but PyPi still delivers an old release of Pycrytpto. You can instead install the latest release directly from the GitHub repository by using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git
```

Comment: I am using VS2017 Community Edition, in the Packages pane I pasted your command but get the following error `Collecting git+https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git
  Cloning https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git to c:\users\smeaden\appdata\local\temp\pip-os9_ijcy-build
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install`

Comment: Sorry, does not work error message `----- Installing 'pip uninstall pycrypto' -----
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages
Collecting uninstall
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement uninstall (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for uninstall
----- Failed to install 'pip uninstall pycrypto' -----`

Comment: This issue might be coming from trying to install/uninstall from within the VS2017 packages pane. Try running the pip commands from cmd.exe.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the VS2017 Packages Pane and install from GitHub using "git+https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git". That Packages Pane is basically a GUI for "pip install" from the command line. If you get an error, try "git+https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git#egg=pycrypto".

Comment: Please use single quotes to delimit the command you're inviting me to run.  It changes the typeface.

Comment: Well we're going round in circles now, that failed because could not find `winrand.c` which OP has highlighted.