# Failed installing pycrypto with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pycrypto

I encountered a problem when I try to download a certain package:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pycrypto

Collecting pycrypto
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\beheer~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-_luv
op\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record c:\users\beheer~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-jct20j\install-record.
txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher

    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py21compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\
Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-2
.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\R
andom\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\
Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Ra
ndom\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Random\O
SRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Rando
m\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Ra
ndom\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Ra
ndom\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfT
est
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTe
st
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\C
rypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\C
rypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Sel
fTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\
SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32
-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\
Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cry
pto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-2
.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cry
pto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cry
pto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cry
pto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.
7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win
32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto
\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> bui
ld\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build
\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win3
2-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.
7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32
-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-
2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\C
rypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-2.
7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win3
2-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\
Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\
SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypt
o\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cr
ypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\S
elfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-2.
7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-2
.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Cry
pto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Pr
otocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protoc
ol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Protoc
ol
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Public
Key
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicK
ey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\PublicKey

    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Publ
icKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Publi
cKey
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Sign
ature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Sig
nature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\Crypto\Signa
ture
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastm
ath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpyt
hon27


----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\beheer~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install- 
_luvop\\pycrypto\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\behee
r~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-jct20j\install-record.txt --single- 
version-ext
ernally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
c:\users\beheer~1\appdata
\local\temp\pip-install-_luvop\pycrypto\
```

I already tried this command:

```
    pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

And this still didnt work.

Comment: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpyt
hon27"

Comment: I've downloaded and installed Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0, but still no luck @PrasadK

Comment: You mean it is still tells you to install Visual C++ 9.0 even after you installed it? Or does it print a different error message now?

Comment: Nope, same error but when I go into my programes, I see its installed @Kubuntuer82

Comment: Could you show the output of `echo %VS90COMNTOOLS%` ?

Comment: And could you also show the output of `echo %VCINSTALLDIR% ` ?

Comment: Please also consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41843310/6854564) answer. Please follow the suggested procedure and let us know whether it fixes the issues.

Comment: I cant find vsvars32.bat @Kubuntuer82

Comment: But knowing the output of `echo %VCINSTALLDIR%` can still be   important anyway

Comment: I dont get any output I just stays at  `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` but I already found a solution, so thanks for helping!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The solution was simple

just

```
    pip uninstall pycrypto
    pip install pycryptodome
```

And every should just work fine, it worked for me!

Comment: This is a _workaround_ rather than a solution, but it is still useful, because according to [this post](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/238) on the "Issues" section of the `pycrypto` official repository, it seems the package has not been maintained at all in the last years. And their recommendation is to install `pycryptodome` instead, since it still creates a `Crypto` package with the same namespace, so it is expected to work with source code based on the `pycrypto` libraries.

Comment: I have the same problem and tried ur solution and faced `WARNING: Skipping pycrypto as it is not installed.`

Answer (score 31):

In some cases it is a dependency issue. It can be solved as follows:
     for `python2` run the following command:
    `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`

For `python3` run

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev`

Comment: This is correct answer! Lack of installed libraries is the reason for this error. Don't hurry to install alternatives.

Comment: Can you please give the alternate command for windows?

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, the installation of SET failed at pycrypto build

Answer (score 6):

I fixed same problem in linux running `sudo apt-get install pythonX.X-dev` before installing pycrypto. Replace pythonX.X with your python version e.g. `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`

Answer (score 2):

you can install `pip install pycryptodomex` as it is the only version that is now independent from the old PyCrypto library.
Note: all modules are installed under the Cryptodome package e.g

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
```

you can read more from official docs here https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/introduction

Answer (score 1):

After so many try with errors, now i have one solution for pycrypto and splunklib

```
Code of my Docker file that need to update :

FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc build- 
essential postgresql libpq-dev vim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/api
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0",  "--port", "3000", "--reload"]
```

requirements.txt have

...

pycryptodome==3.14.1

splunk-sdk==1.6.19

splunklib==1.0.0

....

below error was showing for me when try to run above docker file code

```
            Building wheel for splunk-sdk (setup.py): started

            #9 80.50   Building wheel for splunk-sdk (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

            #9 80.51   Created wheel for splunk-sdk: filename=splunk_sdk-1.6.20-py3-none-any.whl 
            size=124053 sha256=ddce3663bb166c6732e18f1ed95187528c2a666b996eff7dfac00302cf9771d7

            #9 80.51   Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-
            frl315nd/wheels/f7/a1/72/b2474c8ffe6b02fe24078e3413ed668fe6b85dfb17cd8e64c2

            #9 80.51   Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): started

            #9 92.72   Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
            #9 92.76   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

            Running setup.py install for pycrypto: started

            #9 106.8   Running setup.py install for pycrypto: finished with status 'error'

            #9 106.9   error: subprocess-exited-with-error note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

            #9 106.9 error: legacy-install-failure
            #9 106.9 Encountered error while trying to install package.
            #9 106.9 pycrypto
```

**Solution ** - Now i am updating docker file with below code

```
            FROM python:3.8-slim
            RUN mkdir /app
            WORKDIR /app
            COPY requirements.txt /app
            RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc build-essential postgresql libpq-dev vim
            RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libssl-dev libffi-dev
            RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
            COPY . /app
            WORKDIR /app/api
            EXPOSE 3000
            CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0",  "--port", "3000", "--reload"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

installing python3-devel (for python3) helped to solve my problem
details in
[fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Probably correct name for **linux** package is `python3-dev`. And author of question use **windows**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support whatsoever from the project. Specifically in windows. [Pycrypto Issue Link](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues/173).

For ubuntu these answers will work.
But I guess for windows you should switch to pycryptodome as it installs the packages with the same crypto name as pycrypto,

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to copy Crypto folder to path where you have the script.py and complementary files.

You can check the path in IDLE shell

```
import Crypto as cr

print ("Pycryptodome version:"+ cr.__version__)
print (cr.__path__)
```

Comment: cr. __ version __) without space

Answer (score -1):

Create new environment for python project for using command conda create -n env_name python=3.6
you to write python version according to your requirements. after that you can clone your project in that environment. it will work.