# Cannot install/build PyCrypto python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

I'm trying to install `smartapi` package using pip, `pip install smartapi`. During the installation it requires to build/install `PyCrypto` but it is throwing an error while building `PyCrypto`.

OS: Windows 10

Below is the error i'm getting:

```
Collecting smartapi
  Using cached SmartAPI-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: rdflib in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from smartapi) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rdflib-jsonld in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from smartapi) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: isodate in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from smartapi) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from smartapi) (3.17.3)
Collecting PyCrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from smartapi) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from smartapi) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from isodate->smartapi) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from rdflib->smartapi) (2.4.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyCrypto
  Building wheel for PyCrypto (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4mmjh76\\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4mmjh76\\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-s9dv_r4u'
       cwd: C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c4mmjh76\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\
  Complete output (183 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
  copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
  copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
  building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/winrand.obj   
  winrand.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(43): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ','
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(49): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(57): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(64): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(70): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(77): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(83): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(90): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyCrypto
  Running setup.py clean for PyCrypto
Failed to build PyCrypto
Installing collected packages: PyCrypto, smartapi
    Running setup.py install for PyCrypto ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4mmjh76\\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4mmjh76\\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1uf4eqy8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Anaconda\Include\PyCrypto'
         cwd: C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c4mmjh76\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\
    Complete output (183 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src/winrand.obj 
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Wi    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4mmjh76\\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4mmjh76\\pycrypto_d247c0665e7347b58c7187b41496bb1a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = 
f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1uf4eqy8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Anaconda\Include\PyCrypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The `smartapi` library is tagged to be compatible with Python 2. Dependency problems notwithstanding you might end up having trouble using it with Python 3 anyway.

Comment: What is it that you need to do in the end? What do you need `smartapi` for? It seems that library ("A communication library that allows handling Smart API semantic messages as objects") has not been updated in 4 years.

Comment: @AKX I want to fetch stocks data from it.

Comment: So then that is not the right library. If you want to fetch stock data, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/ lets you use Yahoo! Finance data.

Comment: The PyCrypto documentation says *PyCrypto is written and tested using Python version 2.1 through 3.3.* There hasn't been a new release for some years. The download doesn't include a Windows binary, so `pip` is attempting to compile it from source. On Windows that is not always straightforward. Normally I would suggest you look for an unofficial binary on Christoph Gohlke's site, but even he doesn't have PyCrypto. That suggests that building a current Windows binary from source is even more fraught than usual. Follow the recommendations to look for an alternative.

Comment: Well, installing `smartapi-python` did the trick, I am able to fetch the required data. Thank you all for your precious time.

Answer (score 1):

on windows 10, we use pycryptodome instead of pycrypto

> pip uninstall pycrypto

> pip install pycryptodome

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080459/failed-installing-pycrypto-with-pip)

Comment: Won't help much if SmartAPI depends on `pycrypto` and will insist on installing it.

Comment: @AKX exactly, but i found a way around, there was a library for python `smartapi-python`. It worked.

Comment: @dev1ce the `smartapi` and `smartapi-python` libraries seem to be for entirely different uses.

Comment: @AKX oh! so, is there any other way to install `smartapi` without getting a `PyCrypto` error?

Comment: @dev1ce another way you can install `smartapi` is downgrade your python version to lower than 3.3

Answer (score 1):

This happens because *smartapi* uses the older version of PyCrypto.
It can be easily solved by just using the following version.

```
pip install smartapi-python
```

**NOTE:** Many say that this is a different library but don't worry they are one and the same you can try testing it if you need to.