# Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects - ERROR

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I'm facing an error while deploying to Heroku. ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects. However, my project does not specify use for pycrypto. What is causing this issue? My requirements.txt looks like:

- python==3.10.9
- firebase_admin
- pyrebase
- pyrebase4
- dash
- dash_auth
- dash_bootstrap_components
- dash_daq
- pandas
- plotly

```
Heroku CLI output
 Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
remote:
remote:          × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
remote:          │ exit code: 1
remote:          ╰─> [71 lines of output]
remote:              checking for gcc... gcc
remote:              checking whether the C compiler works... yes
remote:              checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
remote:              checking for suffix of executables...
remote:              checking whether we are cross compiling... no
remote:              checking for suffix of object files... o
remote:              checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
remote:              checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
remote:              checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
remote:              checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... yes
remote:              checking for __gmpz_init in -lmpir... no
remote:              checking whether mpz_powm is declared... yes
remote:              checking whether mpz_powm_sec is declared... yes
remote:              checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
remote:              checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
remote:              checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
remote:              checking for ANSI C header files... yes
remote:              checking for sys/types.h... yes
remote:              checking for sys/stat.h... yes
remote:              checking for stdlib.h... yes
remote:              checking for string.h... yes
remote:              checking for memory.h... yes
remote:              checking for strings.h... yes
remote:              checking for inttypes.h... yes
remote:              checking for stdint.h... yes
remote:              checking for unistd.h... yes
remote:              checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
remote:              checking limits.h usability... yes
remote:              checking limits.h presence... yes
remote:              checking for limits.h... yes
remote:              checking stddef.h usability... yes
remote:              checking stddef.h presence... yes
remote:              checking for stddef.h... yes
remote:              checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
remote:              checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
remote:              checking for string.h... (cached) yes
remote:              checking wchar.h usability... yes
remote:              checking wchar.h presence... yes
remote:              checking for wchar.h... yes
remote:              checking for inline... inline
remote:              checking for int16_t... yes
remote:              checking for int32_t... yes
remote:              checking for int64_t... yes
remote:              checking for int8_t... yes
remote:              checking for size_t... yes
remote:              checking for uint16_t... yes
remote:              checking for uint32_t... yes
remote:              checking for uint64_t... yes
remote:              checking for uint8_t... yes
remote:              checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
remote:              checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
remote:              checking for memmove... yes
remote:              checking for memset... yes
remote:              configure: creating ./config.status
remote:              config.status: creating src/config.h
remote:              In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/Python.h:86,
remote:                               from src/_fastmath.c:31:
remote:              /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/cpython/pytime.h:208:60: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaratio 
remote:                208 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_FromTimespec(_PyTime_t *tp, struct timespec *ts);
remote:                    |                                                            ^~~~~~~~
remote:              /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/cpython/pytime.h:213:56: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaratio 
remote:                213 | PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_AsTimespec(_PyTime_t t, struct timespec *ts);
remote:                    |                                                        ^~~~~~~~
remote:              /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.11/cpython/pytime.h:217:63: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaratio 
remote:                217 | PyAPI_FUNC(void) _PyTime_AsTimespec_clamp(_PyTime_t t, struct timespec *ts);
remote:                    |                                                               ^~~~~~~~
remote:              src/_fastmath.c:33:10: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
remote:                 33 | #include <longintrepr.h>                                /* for conversions */
remote:                    |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:              compilation terminated.
remote:              error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:              [end of output]
remote:
remote:          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
remote:          Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
remote:          Building wheel for sseclient (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for sseclient (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for sseclient: filename=sseclient-0.0.27-py3-none-any.whl size=5565 sha256=30988661931e8740f4a7ee87948f5f69e2803cb6d31179cbe4cb6e9bbea1241e
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-ivcb6vdl/wheels/7c/54/eb/a223b1599728ecaf0528281c17c96c503aa7d18a752a4e4e3a
remote:          Building wheel for jwcrypto (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for jwcrypto (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for jwcrypto: filename=jwcrypto-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl size=90472 sha256=b9d97dca4df5d53e6f69d6e0c7c0406fdb519a521a08f8e15d02bcfff20c8cb3
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-ivcb6vdl/wheels/42/b6/e3/23d953d3b1a939d81aa460121597ac050eaf99d04578eb4340
remote:        Successfully built dash_daq gcloud sseclient jwcrypto
remote:        Failed to build pycrypto
remote:        ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to acuradyne.
remote:
To ##app link 
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Any possible solutions or reasoning behind this problem will be helpful

Answer (score 5):

Try running `pip install setuptools wheel` before installing requirements.txt. Some legacy projects require these packages to build wheels for pyproject.toml based projects. If that doesn't work, you might look into pycryptodome as a replacement for this dependency as mentioned in this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099842/19581102

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because I had both pyrebase and pyrebase4 inside the requirements.txt

I removed pyrebase and kept pyrebase4. It solved the problem