# i am getting this error while installing simplecrypt in VS Code

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, pypi, pycrypto

```
PS E:\ADV-C186-Student> pip install simple-crypt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting simple-crypt
  Using cached simple_crypt-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycrypto (from simple-crypt)
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Can anyone tell me a perfect solution for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects - ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318098/could-not-build-wheels-for-pycrypto-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject-toml)

Answer (score 0):

The stable release of this package i.e. [simple-crypt 4.1.7](https://pypi.org/project/simple-crypt/#description) was released on June 17, 2015. A package that has not been maintained for many years may have compatibility issues especially if you are using a recent version of Python.

Perhaps you could try what your error message says and see if it fixes the issue: it says you should get Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/