# Can't install pycrypto

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install pycrypto for python 3 on windows, but it just keeps throwing an error about cl.exe failed with exit status 2.

I have visual studio 2017 installed, with build tools, and it's still throwing the error. I've tried running as administrator, trying to install it manually, nothing is working. Please help.

Output:

`C:\Users\Computer\Desktop>python -m pip install pycrypto
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d7yv005p\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t0teikv0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -IC:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(43): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(49): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(57): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(64): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(70): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(77): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(83): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(90): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
Command "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d7yv005p\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t0teikv0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7yv005p\pycrypto\`

Comment: Your output is all text. Copy the text and paste it here. Don't post screenshots of text, that's useless to anyone who might google the same error.

Comment: Can't, full output is too long. Can't use pastebin without code, either.

Comment: Of course you can post it here. There is no length limit.

Comment: Comments have a length limit, no idea how to style it in the question without it looking unreadable.

Comment: I did not say "paste it into a comment". :) Edit your post, that's why posts are editable.

Comment: Sometimes installing packages through pip requires some system wide compiler to compile stuff. Now on linux this usually works out of the box, but on Windows I've encountered a lot of problems with similar situations. My two cents are to try and install a pre-built version of the package using a wheel file for example: https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Windows Python-3.6 PyCrypto installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error)

Answer (score 6):

This helps me (Win 10, Python 3.7.4):

1. `pip3 install pycryptodome`
2. `pip3 install --no-deps simple-crypt`

Comment: the question is asking about ```pycrypto ``` not ```pycryptodome```. do you have any solution for ```pycrypto ```?

Comment: @Bogota I agree that this answer is not about pycrypto, but it is indeed a working solution and serves the purpose.

Comment: @Bogota `pycryptodome` could be replaced by `pycrypto`. Take a look at their [compatibility](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/vs_pycrypto.html#compatibility-with-pycrypto)

Answer (score 3):

for python 3.7 and VS 2019 I've followed the post [41843266](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error), which explains how to include the stdint.h library in order to install pycrypto:

1. You should find the folder name "14.xx.xxxxx" in the VS 2019 MSVC path (In my laptop C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508")
2. open "x86_x64 Cross-Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" with administrator privilege from the start menu.
3. set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\stdint.h" (Be sure to replace the folder name previously found)
4. Then try again installing pycrypto

Hope it can help you

Comment: Note that the key is `%VCINSTALLDIR%` environment variable must set correct path relative to `set CL=/FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%\\INCLUDE\\stdint.h`, so always ensures the `%VCINSTALLDIR%` path in environment variable is the parent path of INCLUDE folder (if not found, try to find in sub-sub-directories, the path seems keep changing), rather than follow online tutorial which the path changed over time.