# Pip install allennlp

Tags: python, pip, nlp, cl

I use python 3.11 and am trying to pip install allennlp, but there is an error message:

```
        thinc/linalg.cpp(196): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I have the C++ build tools (MVSC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools) installed, and when I look inside the its include directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include for me), it indeed does not contain the longintrepr.h file. Wonder what the next step of solving this would be, thx!

I have looked at another [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694099/cant-install-pycrypto) and one answer suggests setting the command line option to include stdint.h in the x86_x64_Cross-Tools Command Prompt for VS 20xx before pip install:

```
set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\14.xx.xxxxx\include\stdint.h"
```

I have added a system variable called VCINSTALLDIR with the directory set as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC) and tried the above suggestion, but the same error message persists.