# Installing pycrypto on windows (popular solution not working)

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycrypto

I need to install pycrypto for a project that requires pycrypto. PyCryptodome is not an option, sadly.

I have tried what everybody seems to recommend, aka powershell commands [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843266/microsoft-windows-python-3-6-pycrypto-installation-error) but to no avail.

I set VCINSTALLDIR in my user vars to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\`.
I double checked that `stdint.h` is indeed at `VCINSTALLDOR\Tool\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\`.
I then ran

`set CL=-FI"%VCINSTALLDOR%Tool\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\stdint.h"`

and

`pip install pycrypto`

still no luck. Tried it both with and without admin privileges.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't get a good feedback here, try posting the same question at superuser.com  - as it is more related with environment than coding.

Answer (score 0):

for me "pip install pycrypto" for some reason my command prompt thinks install is the module so I have to use "python -m pip pycrypto" might be a last ditch effort but if you end up being desperate might as well try it :/

Comment: As far as I know the issue is missing information in some header file of the pycrypto package. `python -m` does not magically fix that I think. Tried it anyway, but no success.